# Complicated Inner Product

Tags: linear-algebra

$\textbf{Problem.}$ Compute for $c = y^{T}A$ given
$$
y = (u_{1},\ldots, u_{n}, v_{1},\ldots,v_{m}) \\
A= \begin{bmatrix} B \\ C \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $B=\begin{pmatrix} I & 0  & \dots  & 0 \\
     0 & I  & \dots  & 0 \\
     \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\
     0 & 0  & \dots  & I 
\end{pmatrix}$, a $n \times nm$ matrix  and $C=\begin{pmatrix}
    e^{1} & e^{1}  & \dots  & e^{1} \\
    e^{2} & e^{2}  & \dots  & e^{2} \\
    \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\
    e^{m} & e^{m}  & \dots  & e^{m}
    \end{pmatrix}$, a $m \times nm$ matrix with $I=(1,\ldots,1)$ and $e^{i}_{k}=\delta_{i,k}$ (the Kronecker Delta).

I was told to try it first with $m=2$. But I'm still not sure how to do it. Can someone walk me through the process?

Comment: Hint: $y^TA = u^TB + v^TC$

Comment: Try $n = m = 2$ and write out $\begin{bmatrix}B\\C\end{bmatrix}$ explicitly. That is, the actual elements, no submatrix notations.